# Any resources for moving/integrating a website onto Rackspace for first time?

Tags: rackspace

I'm writing a web app and would like to use a Rackspace managed solution. My app works on my local computer but I'd like to move it over to the managed cloud environment with Rackspace.

I'm just wondering what's in the middle that I need to learn how to do? Any good resources on that?

Comment: on what technology/language to make your application?

Comment: It's written in PHP/MYSQL...

Comment: Exactly which Rackspace product are you looking at?

Answer (score 1):

if it's all on the same server things like 'localhost' would make this easy to work with.  if you have references to machine names or ips in connection strings that you might have to change/

Comment: Also I would try to use hostnames over IP addresses.  If you change IPs then you can just update the hosts file or DNS records.

Answer (score 0):

If you aren't very far into development I would just do your development on Rackspace.  No surprises.  But if you can't / don't want to I suggest just setting up the exact same OS version.  Rackspace uses a custom kernel, but I think that should be enough to cover any nasty surprises.